# How to turn onclick function to default text when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am using an onClick method to change the text of an element, I have a 3x3 grid layout and the below is an example of one square in this grid. Currently if I click each square they will all change their text but I would like to return to the default text located in the p tag when another element is clicked.

```
onClick="changeText('Some text blah blah blah.','home-grid-one-two')" 
<p style="text-align: center;">Measurable</p>
```

At the moment this is the JavaScript function which the onClick calls

```
function changeText(text, ele)


     { 
            var display = document.getElementById(ele);
            display.innerHTML = "";
            display.style.textAlign = "center";
            display.style.fontSize = "1em";
            display.innerHTML = text;
        }
```

Comment: Which kind of `another DIV`? Any DIV or just sepcific ones? You have to provide more context regarding your question. What about a MCVE? FYI, this line is useless: `display.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks I will remove that useless line of code and sorry I mean that each element should return to default text when another is clicked. I have a tile layout that changes the text when the user clicks on a square

Comment: @A.Wolff so for example the first piece of code is for one element which changes then when another element e.g. home-grid-one-three is clicked I want any previous text to return to default

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the previous values, then restore them when clicking another element.

```
var previousElement = null;
var previousText = "";

function changeText(text, ele) { 
  //restore previous values
  if(previousElement) {
    previousElement.innerHTML = previousText;
  }

  //store the values
  previousElement = document.getElementById(ele);
  previousText = previousElement.innerHTML;

  previousElement.innerHTML = ""; //this isn't required
  previousElement.style.textAlign = "center";
  previousElement.style.fontSize = "1em";
  previousElement.innerHTML = text;
}
```

EDIT: With the updated question, you asked about using the value from the p tag. You could do that.

I would give the p tag an id, like "#previousText". Then update the changeText() method to:

```
var previousElement = null;

function changeText(text, ele) { 
  var previousText = document.getElementById("previousText");

  //restore previous values
  if(previousElement) {
    previousElement.innerHTML = previousText.innerHTML;
  }

  //store the values
  previousElement = document.getElementById(ele);
  previousText.innerHTML = previousElement.innerHTML;

  previousElement.innerHTML = ""; //this isn't required
  previousElement.style.textAlign = "center";
  previousElement.style.fontSize = "1em";
  previousElement.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: thank you this solution kind of makes sense to me but as I have the previous value in a p tag would it be better to pass the function a third argument which would be the value in the p tag?

Comment: The original question was worded a bit odd; I didn't realize you had stored the value in a p tag. You could pass the value from the p tag, but what if later on the value in the p tag deviates from the value in the grid? i.e. in the grid you display "Measurable", but in the p tag you display "You clicked Measurable!". It might be cleaner to keep the display logic separate from the business logic.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you've designed it such that there's a pattern to the IDs of all the divs you want to control like this (say they all begin with "home-grid"), then you could do something like

```
$("[id=^home-grid]").innerHTML=<whatever your default text is>;
```

to return all of them to the default text, then change the one you've clicked to the text you want. If all of them have different default texts you might have to do something slightly more complex, but the theory of the method would be the same.